# iOS 13.3.1 shows .sqlite file under App's folder

Tags: ios

After updating iOS 13.3.1, Files app shows **".sqlite"** files under App's folder.

```
Files -> On My iPhone -> [APP]
```

Is it iOS bug ?
Will it cause any problems ?

**Note*** I checked my other mobile with iOS 12.2 it doesn't have this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s because this app has put this SQLite database file in the documents folder rather than the application support folder. See [iOS Storage Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/204/).

> Will it cause any problems?

Yes, you are exposing internal implementation details to users, it’s a potential security issue (if you have anything confidential in that database) and anyone with access to that device can now easily extract everything in that database. And a user theoretically could even alter this database, breaking the app or changing its behavior.

You definitely want to have the app check to see if this file exists in the Documents directory, and if so, programmatically move it to the Application Support directory and open it from there from that point on.